# changing a file's single character

Tags: php, file-io

I need to change a single character in a file.
I'd rather not use an auxiliary file like so (pseudo code):
`read(theFile)`

`change(theFile)`

`write(theFile2)`

`erase(theFile)`

`rename(theFile2,theFile)`

Since in this way, Some process can require that file when it is actually erased.
Rather, I'd like to operate on that own file, because this way, I count on the server's os to take care of timing and process access to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use `flock` to lock the file. Example based on code from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/flock):

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("file.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    //make your changes
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In place editing is possible, but depending on what you want can be quite difficult. For example, this code:

```
<?php

$r = fopen("test.txt", "c+");
fseek($r, 50);

// write out
fwrite($r, "TESTING");
fclose($r);
```

will open up a file called `test.txt` and insert the word *TESTING* into the file 50 bytes in. Once you close the handle the file will be saved with the changes: no need to do a full on replace. In this way you can **add** data to the internals of the file. I could not see in any of the PHP functions a way to **remove** parts of the file, so if you need to delete anything you're probably out of luck and will have to overwrite the entire file.

EDIT: this requires PHP 5.2.6 or higher, as far as I can tell from the [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) docs.