# testing locking a file

Tags: php

I [locked a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487505/changing-a-files-single-character/10487534#10487534) and I am trying to test how the system reacts to a locked file. 
I would like other processes to wait for the process to be released until they can `require_once` that file again and not to come back with an error.

The problem is no matter what I do, I don't seem to be able to lock the file and do some waiting while another process asks for the file, and see the reaction of the system to that locked file.

I tried
1. `sleep()` which doesn't work, it halts the whole php engine.
2. I created a batch file that simply pauses until you hit enter. and used `exec("cmd.exe /c START c:\\1.bat");`

So the hunch is that all processes are actually being one serial queue of tasks, so that if one is paused for any reason, so are all others ?

so How can I test if a file is locked ?
But of course if I am right, what's the point in locking the file whatsoever if other processes can't access it anyway?

Comment: That's the point of locking a file exclusively. No one else shall be able to access it.

Comment: You've got 2 scripts, one that locks a file, one that wait's for the file to be released in order to require it?

Comment: One script should lock the file and hold. I would like to see what happens when the other script does a 'require_once' for it.

Comment: Try creating an infinite loop. May lead to an timeout if you let it run for too long, but I guess that should be fine just to test it.

Comment: as expected. Both files are halted for 30 seconds default timeout.

Comment: This may lead to the conclusion that the require just waits for the file to be released again.

Comment: @Ahatius, This is not true. I just ran another script that is not requiring the locked file at all, and it still halts.

Comment: As you see in my answer, I don't have any halts at all. Do you call each script, or does one script execute them?

Comment: I just tested your code, the lock doesn't affect file3.php... When I try to open using explorer, the file is locked though....

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. File3 doesn't have a problem requiring the file. As I said, the flock obviously is for other scripts/programs than php. If you want the require to wait until the flock has been unset, check if an flock exists, and if not, require it. But I'm not sure about this, you might want someone else to explain flock behaviour.

Comment: Please add the flock check to the answer, it is very important, although require_once is not handling a file, and thus no blocking will occur for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = fopen('somefile.php', 'r+');

while(!flock($file, LOCK_SH | LOCK_NB)) {
    sleep(1);
}

require 'somefile.php';
```

Since flock doesn't seem to work within php scripts, you need to check if a lock is present.

Comment: The sleep would not cut it because it halts the whole system

Comment: Depends, if the script is called by some parent script, then it'll halt them all. It won't halt the whole server. A sleep in one script doesn't effect a script which was called separately. I just put sleep in there to keep the CPU usage low, maybe there's another way to keep CPU usage down while looping. I'm assuming that the file, checking for the file lock is called separately.

Answer (score 1):

the `require_once` is handled by php. Because of that, you cannot simply acquire a lock for it AFAIK.
If you look at file locking, refer to [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch18_25.htm)
It states that you should use locks whenever you try to access the locked file.